# Type does not conform to protocol 'UIViewControllerRepresentable'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to create a video player in SwiftUi with a AVPlayerViewController. I found that I have to use a struct that conforms to the UIViewControllerRepresentable protocol

```
struct AVPlayerControllerRepresented : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = AVPlayerViewController
    
    var player : AVPlayer
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

but Xcode keeps saying it doesn't conform

I tried pressing the fix button next to the error but it just adds the same functions that are already there

```
func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        <#code#>
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        <#code#>
    }
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure you're importing `AVKit` and your code should work. (No need for the `typealias`)

```
import AVKit

struct AVPlayerControllerRepresented: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var player: AVPlayer

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
    
    }
}
```

Comment: and you need to move setting the player into `updateUIViewController `

Comment: I deleted the typealias and AVKit is already imported and it's still not working